# How to test method that uses a image in tmp folder with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to test (with rspec) a method that will decide color given a png file. In my application this file is in the /tmp folder. But how do I do that in test?

```
def decide_background(background, screenshot_path)
  background = background.delete(" ")

  self.screenshot = screenshot_path
  self.background = background

  unless screenshot_path.nil? || screenshot_path.empty?
    image = ChunkyPNG::Image.from_file(screenshot_path)
    background = ImageManipulation::get_bg_from_edges(image).delete(" ")
    unless background.empty?
      self.background = background
    end
  end

  if self.background == 'rgba(0,0,0,0)'
    self.background = 'rgb(255,255,255)'
  end

  self.save
end
```

This method receives two parameters: 
1 - background: String of type '`rgb(0,0,0)`' 
2 - screenshot_path: Path to where screenshot is stored, located in `/tmp/#{name_of_file}`

I want to make sure that the method actually stores the correct background. So, I guess I would need to mock `ImageManipulation::get_bg_from_edges(image).delete(" ")` to avoid the dependency, because I am not testing that method. But how would I do that?

Also, how would I pass the screenshot_path? Should I create a file in my /tmp folder for this unit test?

Comment: Are you writing an integration test (maybe an rspec feature test) or a unit test?

Comment: It's a unit test. I tried to simplify the method, but I edited to show the complete form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that this is a unit test, you should mock `from_file`. There's no benefit in testing ChunkyPNG; I trust its authors already tested it for you. In your examples for this method:

```
image = double image # ha, I said "double image"
expect(ChunkyPNG::Image).to receive(:from_file).with(# whatever screenshot path should be) { image }
expect(ImageManipulation).to receive(:get_bg_from_edges).with(image) { # whatever background you like }
```

You probably want an integration test that hits this code too (in fact I'd have written that first), and then you would actually want an image on the disk to read. Whether you'd need to put it there as part of the integration test setup or whether your app should put it there depends on your app.

Comment: But how would you mock from_file? And also, how would you mock ImageManipulation::get_bg_from_edges(image).delete(" ")?? I mean, from within my rspec code that tests the instance method decide_background, how would I mock that?

Comment: Thanks Dave. However, I don't understand this:  expect(your_object).to receive(:get_bg_from_edges).with(image) - What your_object be? expect(your_object).to receive(:get_bg_from_edges).with(image) it's a module that I am using in that method.